# Gitlab-CI Date variable for test file name

Tags: bash, yaml, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

My program has a log file that it outputs when it completes.  I'd like for that output file to be named by the date when it was run.

I've tried setting a date variable, as well as adding it in line.  [This post](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/1664) says it works in line, but I'm having no luck with that method.

My current gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
    MyProjectEXE: My\Project\myproject.exe
    MSBuild: C:\Path\to\my\MSBuild.exe
    Solution: C:\Path\to\my\project.sln

stages:
    - build
    - test

build:
    stage: build
    script: '"%MSBuild%" "%Solution%"'

test:
    stage: test
    script:
    - '"%MSBuild%" "%Solution%"'
    - '%MyProjectEXE%" --results C:\path\to\my\results\log-$(date + \"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S\").csv
```

The second script under test just outputs a file named

```
C:\path\to\my\results\log-$(date
```

I've tried creating a variable that holds the date at the top, and putting it there, and I've tried just about every form of quotes around that log file name.

Comment: You are executing this on a Windows CI runner?

Comment: Yes, it is a windows CI runner.

Comment: the quoting of `%MyProjectEXE%` on the last line is effed up.  might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

this could solve your problem https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/22901

use CI_JOB_STARTED

- '%MyProjectEXE%" --results C:\path\to\my\results\log-${CI_JOB_STARTED}.csv

or at the current time in a before statement